# SSAS Cube in Excel Connection issues

Tags: excel, ssas

So I have a monthly report that exists in excel with a connection to an SSAS cube.

Recently we have had to make a change to the Cube, specifically with regard to a date dimension and rolling over to 2014.

Here is the issue - If I connect to the cube from a fresh excel file, the data gets pulled in just fine, however if i simply refresh the existing excel file that already has the pivot tables connected to the cube and the connection already established, I can view updated data for the months that existed previously, but I am missing the most recent month of data.

Both of the connections in the excel files are pointing to the same saved connection string in my "my documents > my data sources" folder.

Interestingly, if i copy the pivot table from the file that isn't displaying the data correctly, and paste it into a new file, the connection gets re established and the data gets pulled in. Furthermore, if I create a new pivot table from that same connection in the SAME FILE it pulls in the correct data.

I am at a loss, is there something about the way the pivot table interacts with the connection that I am missing?

Here is an image, I have redacted any company / personal information but it shouldn't affect anything.

[image: http://imgur.com/FYboIPi]

Comment: It is not just a filter applied that excludes the newest years months?

Comment: Correct it is not just a filter.

Comment: @kerui I'm having exactly the same issue, did you manage to solve it?